# OpenCVsharp: Live streaming

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, video-streaming, wowza

I am working on a project which requires to stream to wowza streaming server using RTSP or RTMP. I know how to capture the video. I tried using the CvVideoWrier. But it didn't really work.

```
CvCapture cap = CvCapture.FromCamera(0);
            cap.SetCaptureProperty(CaptureProperty.FrameHeight, pictureBox1.Height);
            cap.SetCaptureProperty(CaptureProperty.FrameWidth, pictureBox1.Width);
            while (true)
            {
                IplImage img = cap.QueryFrame();
                Bitmap bm = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(img);
                bm.SetResolution(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
                pictureBox1.Image = bm;

                img = null;
                bm = null;
            }
```

This is what I did till now. Please help me.. I am stuck at this point for more than 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using OpenCvSharp;

namespace EdgeDetect
{
    class Template
    {
        public Template()
        {
            CvCapture cap = CvCapture.FromCamera(1);
            CvWindow w = new CvWindow("Template Matching");

            IplImage tpl = Cv.LoadImage("speedlimit55.jpg", LoadMode.Color);

            CvPoint minloc, maxloc;

            double minval, maxval;

            while (CvWindow.WaitKey(10) < 0)
            {
                IplImage img = cap.QueryFrame();
                IplImage res = Cv.CreateImage(Cv.Size(img.Width - tpl.Width + 1, img.Height - tpl.Height + 1), BitDepth.F32, 1);
                Cv.MatchTemplate(img, tpl, res, MatchTemplateMethod.CCoeff);
                Cv.MinMaxLoc(res, out minval, out maxval, out minloc, out maxloc, null);
                Cv.Rectangle(img, Cv.Point(minloc.X, minloc.Y), Cv.Point(minloc.X + tpl.Width, minloc.Y + tpl.Height), CvColor.Red, 1, 0, 0);
                w.Image = img;
                Cv.ReleaseImage(res);
                Cv.ReleaseImage(img);
            }
        }
    }
}
```